# Migrate Flex Application from Adobe LiveCycle DS to Blaze DS

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, livecycle, lcds

I'm a begginer in Flex and working on an application where I need to migrate the existing Flex code from LiveCycle DS to Blaze DS. The flex application use only the RPC features and current flex version is 4.5

**Please suggest**

**1)** How do I migrate my code in Flex Builder? (Does re-creating the project by using Blaze DS instead of LiveCycle DS alone suffice?)

**2)** How do I make sure that the code is migrated properfly (Which files/configuration settings to double check & confirm for this)

**3)** Do I need to re-create the RPC objects as well? (Or simply the automatic migration from Flex builder will take care of this?)

Thank in Advance.

Comment: I think in this case it depends on what parts of LiveCycle DS you are using. If you are using only the AMF RPC stuff then the change should be painless. The main difference here is (as I recall) that the StreamingConnections in LiveCycle use non blocking mechanisms while the BlazeDS implementation use Blocking IO (Will probably be addressed by the community as soon as BlazeDS is fully donated to Apache)

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. Can you also share some URL where I might find all such differences. TIA.

Comment: Does this help? http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2008/01/31/blazeds-and-lcds-feature-difference/